# XTEXT based DSL Save All before Build

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

I have Eclipse RCP DSL application. Build All option does not work in case end user does not save manually all changed files.
I need to find the following :
- Can I save all DSL source file automatically when user click "Build All" menu item. From other hand I have to set "Save Before Build" option programmaticaly

Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Save automatically before build' option in the Preferences in 'General > Workspace'.

If this option is set the build action does something like:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();

for (IWorkbenchWindow window : windows) {
    IWorkbenchPage[] pages = window.getPages();

    for (IWorkbenchPage page : pages) {
        page.saveAllEditors(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can I do it programatically when application starts?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to set flag in 'General->Workspace->Save automatocally before build" - programmaticaly. For example I can switch off automation build by desc = workspace.getDescription();
 desc.setAutoBuilding(false);
Can I do the same for saving?

Comment: It is a preference setting, you would have to work out which preference to set.